# Indie pop music video with lovers on a couch

Tags: pop-music

I am looking for a song, of which I only remember the music video. In the video, you see a variety of different couples sitting on the same couch one after the other in a brightly lit living room. As far as I remember, there are heterosexual couples and gay couples, families with children, becoming parents, young and old couples and one sad person sitting alone with a photograph of their deceased partner.

The genre was indie pop/folk, as far as I can remember. I would assume that the era was late 1990s or early 2000s.

Can anyone tell me the name of the song?

Comment: Hey, this kind of questions (song identification) are not handled by the music p&t. As it seems the music fans stack exchange (https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) does also not allow song identification (check https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But maybe you could try the chat of the music fans stack exchange.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Reddit helped btw https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/sp34v/tomtmusic_video_a_sweet_music_video_featuring/.